# How to get a multidemensional array from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, content-management-system, categories

I know the title may not be exactly what this is about but bear with me.
I don't know how another title for this.

Well look this is my situation.
I'm building a  little cms system (for myself and to learn from it). I want the pages inside the CMS to be listed and ordered by categories.
It will look something like this:

```
Webpages
- Home
  -- homepage(this is the web page itself)
- News
  -- Latest news
  -- Archive
```

this system would mean I will have sub-categories.

In the database I have made a table:

```
| ID | Parent_ID |   Name   |   Lable   | Order|
  1        1       Webpages    webpages     1
  2        1       Home        home         1
  3        1       News        news         2
```

As you can see here the main category is the Webpages category and Home and News are sub-categories of it.
And those 2 categories are ordered so the Home category is first then the News second.

The problem I'm facing is this:
If i want to get all the sub-categories means i need to start with the main category Webpages and with that ID i can get the sub-categories of the main category.

I think you can see how deep this can go en that would mean (I think) that there will eventually be many query's that will be run for each sub-category.

So my question is:
Is there a way to get all the sub-categories at once in the correct order in one ore 2 query's.

if you have an answer, please let me know.

thnks

Answer (score 0):

When writing the query you will need to use the ORDER BY clause. For this specific example you will need to ORDER BY Parent_ID, Order. This will return sorted by Parent_ID and then sub sorted by Order.

You can then use mysql_fetch_assoc() for parse the result set into an associative array.

Since you are going to have multiple levels of hierarchy you will have to loop through the result set once store it in a associative array consisting of the hierarchy structure.

This array can then be used to display the appropriate navigation hierarchy on the page.